# Django: Entering instances of classes with empty collections

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application with following class:

```
class Opinion(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contents = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    proArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Pro arguments", related_name='proargs', null='true', blank='true')
    contraArguments = models.ManyToManyField('self', verbose_name="Contra arguments", related_name='contraarg', null='true', blank='true')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.contents
```

When I try to create a new instance of this class in the admin, the newly created opinion has one `proArgument` and one `contraArgument`, even though I didn't enter them.

[image]

What can I do in order for `proargs` and `contraarg` to be empty, when I don't enter them?

Comment: Why are you relating your arguments to 'self'?

Comment: @arie Let's say I have an opinion A. There are opinions B, C and D, which support A and there are opinions E, F, G, which refute it. B, C, D are stored in `proArgs` collection, E, F and G are stored in the `contraArg` collection. A-G are all instances of the same class `Opinion`.

Comment: You don't need `null=True` for a many to many field. Just `blank=True` is enough. Also, you should use `True` instead of the string `'true'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple select widget for both many to many fields contains all possible `Opinions`. In your screenshot, there are no `Opinions` selected for these fields. They are not selected until you click on one or more opinions and save.

You might find the [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) and `filter_vertical` model admin options helpful. They make it clearer which objects are selected.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no error as such (a newly created instance does not have any elements in `proArgs` and `contraArg` collections) ?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko If you're not sure, the simplest way to verify it is to open ``manage.py shell``, ``get()`` the instance and see for yourself.

Comment: Yes, the newly created argument does not have any associated `proArguments` or `contraArguments`. You can verify this in the shell, as @lqc suggests.